# What does @Value annotation mean in Constructor depedency injection in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a snippet that looks like this

```
@Component
public class Inspiration {
        private String lyric =
            "I can keep the door cracked open, to let light through";
        public Inspiration(
            @Value("For all my running, I can understand") String lyric) {
            this.lyric = lyric;
        }
        public String getLyric() {
            return lyric;
        }
        public void setLyric(String lyric) {
            this.lyric = lyric;
        }
}
```

What does `@Value("For all my running, I can understand")`  mean here, does it represent the default value for parameter lyric?

Comment: This explains what it does, and provides a small program you can use to run it: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=N-U5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=@Value(%22For+all+my+running,+I+can+understand%22)+String+lyric)&source=bl&ots=lOIHkwqD8i&sig=ACfU3U1XUOgL4B4gA2OgOx6T8A9Ao5MEUw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjal4Xl3tH4AhXRhGMGHXZJC2UQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%40Value(%22For%20all%20my%20running%2C%20I%20can%20understand%22)%20String%20lyric)&f=false

Answer (score -1):

i hope you can get your explanation here : https://books.google.co.in/books?id=N-U5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=@Value(%22For+all+my+running,+I+can+understand%22)&source=bl&ots=lOIHkwsF8l&sig=ACfU3U2CAxlxIuYSh3A7dvCaQZiVmLauGw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVlun_5tH4AhUeaGwGHcvPB8UQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%40Value(%22For%20all%20my%20running%2C%20I%20can%20understand%22)&f=false

Comment: Link only answers are not a good idea, as the underlying page can easily disappear.